# VBA code saving as in outlook folder path is throwing runtime error

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Auto save specific emails from outlook inbox every month on a hard drive.

I want to be able to auto save specific emails from the outlook inbox every month that is having a keyword "Approve" or "Approved" and not case sensitive and sent from a specific sender.

1. I get an error in the folder path provided for save as
2. I want to also tweak the code to be able to work every month (example run macro after the date that emails are available in inbox each month - say 3rd week of month)
3. I want to tweak the code to only save emails from specific sender, specific subject and specific content

```
Option Explicit

Sub outlooksavefile()

    Dim o As Outlook.Application
    Set o = New Outlook.Application

    Dim ons As Outlook.Namespace
    Set ons = o.GetNamespace("mapi")

    Dim fol As Outlook.Folder
    Set fol = ons.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Test")

    Dim omail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set omail = o.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    For Each omail In fol.Items
        omail.SaveAs "H:\2019" & omail.Subject & ".msg"
    Next omail

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to S.O.! In general, try not to ask multiple questions in a single question. (points 2. and 3. seem like additional questions) Additionally, provide the specific message you get from the error, and any research you have done in order to find what the issue is or might mean. I.e. what is `omail.Subect` --- does it return a valid string?

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure, that each found item in your folder is an email by checking its `Class`.

Concerning the error: Maybe you'r not allowed to write there or - more likely - some characters in the email's subject are forbidden in your filesystem. I added some code to replace forbidden characters.

If you loop over each email, then it's not necessary to generate an additional new email by `CreateItem` before.

```
Option Explicit

Sub outlooksavefile()
    Dim o As Outlook.Application
    Set o = New Outlook.Application

    Dim ons As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set ons = o.GetNamespace("mapi")

    Dim fol As Outlook.Folder
    Set fol = ons.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Test")

    Dim omail As Object
    For Each omail In fol.Items
        If omail.Class = olMail Then  ' olMail = 43
            Debug.Print omail.Sender
            Debug.Print omail.Subject
            Debug.Print omail.Sender
            Debug.Print Left(omail.Body, 20)
            omail.SaveAs Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\" & _
                AllowedChars(omail.Subject) & ".msg", olMSG ' olMSG = 3
        End If
    Next omail
End Sub

Private Function AllowedChars(ByRef s As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim myChar As String
    AllowedChars = s
    For i = 1 To Len(AllowedChars)
        myChar = Mid$(AllowedChars, i, 1)
        If myChar Like "[<>:""/\|?*]" Or Asc(myChar) < 32 Then
            Mid$(AllowedChars, i, 1) = "_"
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Concerning your question 2: Please raise another question after you've gotten this running.

Concerning question 3: I added some debug informations to see, how senders and other email items are stored. Based on that you may generate some If-conditions.

Comment: I tried executing the above code as it is and I get the error - Run Time error 13. Type mismatch. And when I click on Debug, it navigates to the line  Next omail.    I googled the error code and it states the below.

Comment: My fault: If I declare omail as MailItem, it is useless to check its class afterwards, to ensure it's an email - so I changed its declaration to `Object`. By that it  can be any item in your folder.

Comment: I reran the above code to declare omail as object. I do not get any error. But how can I ensure I have the emails saved. I do not see any saved emails in the location that is provided within the code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I also tried adding If-conditions, but I think it is wrong as I am not seeing the files on the folder location?  I want to save the email, when the sender is any one of the 4 names listed and body content contains "approve" which is not case sensitive. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Before filtering the sender please ensure that a test email is saved. Put one test email with subject "This is a test" into the subfolder "Test" of your inbox. Run the code step by step with F8 and see if it is saved.

Comment: I tried this by stepping into the code, but am still not seeing saved email on the folder. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: My example code tries to store them in your personal documents-folder.

Comment: I provided my personal folder location in the code and strangely am not seeing the file.  I also stepped into the code and the code finds the email in the sub folder called test under the inbox in outlook. Am unable to figure out why. Thanks so much for your help, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It is your responsibility to ensure that the file name does not contain invalid characters (such as ":" or "\") - your code uses the message subject as-is.

Comment: Is ":" permitted? email subject contains "RE: Seeking your approval for DQ Checks'

Comment: No, of course not - it is a drive separator (as in "c:\")